# pact-broker docker image is not running after restarting docker machine

Tags: docker, pact, pact-broker

I am using Postgres image and past broker image in my docker machine for setting up pact broker.
here are 4 steps that have mentioned :

**1.**`$ docker run --name pactbroker-db -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=ThePostgresPassword -e POSTGRES_USER=admin -e PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata -v /var/lib/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres`

**2.**`$ docker run -it --link pactbroker-db:postgres --rm postgres sh -c 'exec psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U admin'`

**3**.

```
CREATE USER pactbrokeruser WITH PASSWORD 'TheUserPassword';
CREATE DATABASE pactbroker WITH OWNER pactbrokeruser;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE pactbroker TO pactbrokeruser;
```

**4.** `docker run --name pactbroker --link pactbroker-db:postgres -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_USERNAME=pactbrokeruser -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=TheUserPassword -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_HOST=postgres -e PACT_BROKER_DATABASE_NAME=pactbroker -d -p 80:80 dius/pact_broker`

after running this 4 command when I am opening Hal browser in my local system it is working pretty fine. Now I am stopping 2 docker containers pactbroker-db and pactbroker and stopping docker machine.

After sometime I am restarting docker machine and starting the containers by

**$docker start pactbroker-db**  and  **$docker start pactbroker** .
containers are getting started but when opening HAL browser I am getting the error "We're sorry, but something went wrong." screenshot attached. 
Is there something wrong when I am starting the docker 2nd time?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIBnv.jpg)

Comment: the Pact Foundation do not own pactbroker-db.  I'm guessing this is just a random person's image.  We can't help you with that.

Comment: pactbroker-db is just the name he assigned the postgres container, that looks OK to me. Can you please share the logs in a gist after you have started it the second time? e.g. `docker logs pact-brokerdb` and `docker logs pactbroker`? This might help us understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by using container given in https://github.com/DiUS/pact_broker-docker   and using proper environment variables in docker-compose.yml of this project.